# Why is it mandatory that there should be a possibility of exception throwing in a try to write a catch?

Tags: java, exception, language-design

I was playing around with some exception programs and came across something which i am surprised i never encountered before.

```
import java.io.*;

class ExceptionTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      System.out.println("hello");
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
      System.err.println("ioexception was thrown!!");
    }
  }
}
```

this raises an compiler error:

```
ExceptionTest.java:10: exception java.io.IOException is never thrown in body of
corresponding try statement
catch(IOException ioe)
^
1 error
```

My question is why is it like that?

Why is the compiler worried about a piece of code it is sure it would never reach. It could have just been a warning instead of a full-fledged error. Afterall we could want to keep the catch block as a backup for some future changes we might make or maybe the programmer just forgot to remove it after some edits.

I know i know it saves us from unnecessary keystrokes etc. etc. But it shouldn't bother compiler that much to raise an error. Or is there some other reason for this??

Also an IOException catch block in the code produces an compiler error but an Exception catch block does not... why is that??
Thnx in advance!!

Comment: I am a beginner but what i would like to add is that you said " Why is the compiler worried about a piece of code it is sure it would never reach"---------actually it is actually you who is sure that there will be no exception------and it is the duty of the compiler to check everything written in a program except the comments-----so the compiler is correct.

Comment: @R122: when i said the compiler is sure it would never reach a code, i deduced it from its own compiler error message which says that the IOException is never thrown from the try block i.e. it will never reach the catch block. so basically its the compiler telling me that the IOException catch block will never be excuted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the Java designers thought the system should help in this way. It's the same situation as this:

```
public class EarlyReturn {
    public void foo() {

        return;

        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

...which also results in a compile-time error. Code which will never be run is a bad thing, and the compiler helps us by letting us know it will never run, and the designers felt it should be an error rather than a warning.

You can change your code to catch `Exception` rather than `IOException` if you like, but although that would make the compiler let you do it, you'd still have code that would never be run (which, again, is a bad thing).

> Also an `IOException` catch block in the code produces an compiler error but an `Exception` catch block does not... why is that??

`IOException` is a *checked* exception, and only checked exceptions are checked in this way (that's why they're called that). There are *checked exceptions*, *unchecked exceptions* (`RuntimeException` and its subclasses), and *errors* (`Error` and its subclasses). Technically, checked exceptions are all exceptions that aren't unchecked exceptions or errors ([Section 11.1.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1)), but — this is a bit of a dark corner — not *all* checked exceptions are checked. Specifically, checked exceptions are checked *unless* they're `Exception` or a *super*class of it. From [Section 11.2.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a `catch` clause can catch checked exception class `E1` and it is not the case that the `try` block corresponding to the `catch` clause can throw a checked exception class that is a subclass or superclass of `E1`, unless `E1` is `Exception` or a superclass of `Exception`.

The entirety of Section 11 is probably worth a read. As you can guess, this is a part of Java that evolved a fair bit in the early days, resulting in this somewhat convoluted definition of what gets checked.

Comment: so what u r saying is that the designers decided to warn us through an error in case we wrote some important piece of code in the non-reachable code.

Comment: Yes you could change the code to do that, but that just sweeps the problem under the carpet.  The real problem is that that catch block *won't* be executed with `ioe` bound to an `IOException`.

Comment: "Technically, checked exceptions are all exceptions that aren't unchecked exceptions or errors (Section 11.1.1 of the JLS), but — this is a bit of a dark corner — not all checked exceptions are checked. Specifically, checked exceptions are checked unless they're Exception or a superclass of it. From Section 11.2.3 of the JLS:"  --Thank you for that.  I was about to ask the same question, but this saved me the trouble. :)

Answer (score 3):

The answers are the same as for the more general question: "Why does the compiler treat unreachable code as an error?".

1. The JLS mandates this - see [JLS 14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21).  Note that the JLS rules for detecting unreachable code specifically cover the case of a `catch` for an exception that cannot be thrown.
2. Treating unreachable code as a compilation error eliminates a whole class of mistakes made by programmers.  That's *why* the JLS mandates this.

On the second point, consider this:

```
try {
     System.out.println("Guards!! Someone is stealing the crown jewels!");
} catch(IOException ioe) {
     CallTheArmy();
}
```

The person who wrote this may think that if we can't alert the guards (due to an IOException) then the army will be called.  In fact, that won't happen because `println` will silently eat the IOException.

In that case, you'd be glad that the compiler told you about the problem via a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

Java compilers don't like unreachable code. ([JLS 14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21)) If the programmer forgot to remove the `try ... catch` block then this error will make him remove it. If you make future changes that could throw an `IOException` then the compiler will tell you to include the `try ... catch` block again. It certainly doesn't hurt the code to remove the unnecessary block and will most likely to be easier to read.

EDITED to reflect edited question: "Also an IOException catch block in the code produces an compiler error but an Exception catch block does not... why is that?? Thnx in advance!!"

An exception catch block is more general. It will catch any type of exception (including, say, [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)s) and is therefore reachable code if a `RuntimeException` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Because `IOException` is not `RuntimeException`, so it should be catched only if the block of code inside the `try ... catch` have any the method which declared throws `IOException`.

The reason is: To avoid mistakes of programmer. :) It is the same as the cases of: you return a value in the method, and after the return statement, you have line of code which will be never reached, and this case is always a mistake of programmer.

thagorn's explanation in details: It's true. RuntimeException is "the superclass of those exceptions that can be thrown during the normal operation of the Java Virtual Machine." (JavaDocs). Your compiler knows that there is no way to throw an IOException with your code since it isn't a RuntimeException and isn't explicitly being thrown anywhere.

Comment: m nt sure if its true but even if it is.. my question was why is it like that?? catching an exception which would never be thrown should not be that big an issue with the compiler.

Comment: To avoid mistakes of programmer. :) It is the same as the cases of: you return a value in the method, and after the return statement, you have line of code which will be never reached, and this case is always a mistake of programmer.

Comment: It's true. `RuntimeException` is "the superclass of those exceptions that can be thrown during the normal operation of the Java Virtual Machine." (JavaDocs). Your compiler knows that there is no way to throw an `IOException` with your code since it isn't a `RuntimeException` and isn't explicitly being thrown anywhere.

Comment: I appreciated your explanation more details for my answer. :) And the reason is to Avoid the mistakes as I mentioned. I will update the answer.